# How can I save my data in a json and store it in a database (Django rest framework)

Tags: json, flutter, django-models, django-rest-framework, flutter-dependencies

My code outputs are X and Y each time user touches the app. I want to save All my Xs and Ys in a json file and store it in the server. I use Django rest framework

```html
   
 

  sendToServer() async{
    final res = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('http://localhost:8000/article'),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: json.encode(allPoints)
    );
    print(allPoints);
    print(res?.statusCode);
  }
}
```